# What's the alternative to changing the field type in a TypedDict subclass

Tags: python, python-typing

Doing the following is apparently [not allowed](https://peps.python.org/pep-0589/#inheritance#:%7E:text=Changing%20a%20field%20type) in Python

```python
class ContentBase(TypedDict):
    payload: Any

class ContentA(ContentBase):
    payload: str

class ContentB(ContentBase):
    payload: list[str]
```

e.g. when using Mypy it results in an error

> Overwriting TypedDict field "payload" while extending

TypeScript allows this though:

```ts
interface ContentBase {
  payload: any
}

interface ContentA extends ContentBase {
  payload: string
}

interface ContentB extends ContentBase {
  payload: number
}
```

Is there an equivalent in Python that would work similar to this?

Comment: Obviously, one alternative is *not* changing the field type in a subclass. Maybe you could not specify the `payload` key in `ContentBase` at all?

Comment: I'm not sure why TypeScript would allow it (though the semantics of a `dict` and an interface may be different enough that it makes sense). The Python behavior prevents errors like `d: ContentA = {'payload': 'foo'}; x: ContentBase = d; x['payload'] = 9`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I wanted to make sure that ContentA, ContentB, etc. are similar in shape to each other, and i'm looking for a way to abstract and enforce the keys they have to whatever extent is possible.

Comment: Python 3.11 added support for Generics in `TypedDict`s, would that work for your use-case?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh yes, that pretty much works (only issue being for multiple keys, different TypeVars might have to be passed for complex cases).

You could add your suggestion as an answer if you'd like, and i'll mark it as resolved.