# What is the rationale for not allowing to change field types in TypedDict, even to a subtype, when using inheritance?

Tags: python, inheritance, python-typing

PEP 589 [states](https://peps.python.org/pep-0589/#inheritance):

> Changing a field type of a parent TypedDict class in a subclass is not allowed.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> class X(TypedDict):
>     x: str
>
> class Y(X):
>     x: int  # Type check error: cannot overwrite TypedDict field "x"
> ```

But it gives no further explanation.

And in fact, this is an error e.g. when using this example with Mypy (here, version 0.950):

> error: Overwriting TypedDict field "x" while extending

While it makes sense to me to not allow changing the type entirely (presumably due to the Liskov substitution principle), it seems it is not even allowed to narrow the type of `x` in `Y` to a *subtype* of `x` in `X`:

Changing `str` in `X` to `Any`, `Optional[int]` or `Union[int, str]` all raise the same error.

However, when changing `X` from a `TypedDict` to a `NamedTuple` or a `dataclass`, this then *is* allowed.

Why is this handled more strictly in `TypedDict`?

Comment: This is triggered by this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75997089/whats-the-alternative-to-changing-the-field-type-in-a-typeddict-subclass).

Comment: _"Value types behave invariantly, since `TypedDict` objects are mutable. This is similar to mutable container types such as `list` and `dict`."_ ([PEP 589](https://peps.python.org/pep-0589/#type-consistency))

Comment: As far as I understand now, the point is that `TypedDict` is mutable. But doesn't the same reasoning apply to `dataclass`, or any regular class then?

Comment: This is a very good point. I agree that this seems somewhat arbitrary. Especially because [Mypy rejects covariant subtyping of mutable protocol members](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#covariant-subtyping-of-mutable-protocol-members-is-rejected). Inspired by this I posted the more general question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76005083) in the hopes of capturing the essence of the argument and to see, if someone can tell me, what I have missed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the example from the other question:

```
class ContentBase(TypedDict):
    payload: Any

class ContentA(ContentBase):
    payload: str
```

Not every `ContentBase` can be treated as a `ContentA`, as the `payload` could be some non-`str` type. This means that the two types are not contravariant.

Similarly, not every `ContentA` can be treated as though it was a `ContentBase`, as some code could try to change the `payload` to some non-`str` type. This means that the the two types are not covariant.

As they are neither covariant or contravariant, the two types are invariant, meaning that neither can be treated as a subtype of the other.

You may find [this section of the PEP defining `TypedDict`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0589/#type-consistency)  interesting

Comment: What if Contentbase.payload is a string in both TypedDicts?  I do not understand why mypy still throws an error.

Comment: @coccoinomane Are you sure you're getting the same error? I don't think I would expect it in that circumstance.

Comment: Sadly, I confirm that the code throws the error `Overwriting TypedDict field "payload" while extending  [misc]` (screenshot > https://d.pr/i/Wf1GaQ)  I think the reason is that mypy does not support overriding of TypedDict fields by subclasses, full stop.  Even if the type of the field is a subtype of the type of the parent field.  Even if it is the same type!