# Why is covariant subtyping of mutable members allowed?

Tags: python, mypy, covariance, python-typing

### Invariance of mutable collections

The rationale for why built-in **mutable** collection types in Python are **invariant** is explained well enough in both [PEP 483](https://peps.python.org/pep-0483/#covariance-and-contravariance) and [PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#covariance-and-contravariance) and a nice illustrative example specifically for why `list` is invariant is given in the [Mypy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#variance-of-generic-types) on this topic:

```py
class Shape: ...

class Circle(Shape):
    # The rotate method is only defined on Circle, not on Shape
    def rotate(self): ...

def add_one(things: list[Shape]) -> None:
    things.append(Shape())

my_circles: list[Circle] = []
add_one(my_circles)      # This may appear safe, but
my_circles[-1].rotate()  # this will fail because that last item is now a Shape, not a Circle
```

We can `append` to a list; if `list[Circle]` *were* considered a subtype of `list[Shape]`, calling `add_one` with an argument of the type `list[Circle]` *would* be fine. But that function appends a `Shape` instance to the list, which means it would no longer be of the type `list[Circle]`, and a subsequent attempt to call the last item's `rotate` method would fail.

So in a nutshell, if a complex<sup>1</sup> type is **mutable**, making it covariant with respect to whatever type(s) are contained in it would **not be type safe**. So far so good.

---

### Invariance with mutable *protocol* members

The [Mypy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#covariant-subtyping-of-mutable-protocol-members-is-rejected) also give an explanation along with another example for why covariant subtyping of mutable protocol members is considered **unsafe**:

(Slightly modified by me<sup>2</sup>, using dataclasses for convenience.)

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Protocol

class P(Protocol):
    x: float

def fun(arg: P) -> None:
    arg.x = 3.14

@dataclass
class C:
    x: int

c = C(42)
fun(c)    # This is not safe
c.x << 5  # because this will fail!
```

`C` *seems* like a structural subtype of `P` because its `x` attribute is of the type `int`, which in turn is a subtype of `float`. But Mypy rejects this notion and considers calling `fun` with an instance of `C` to be an **error** because `fun` could (and in this example *does*) **mutate** its argument assigning its `x` attribute a `float` value, and a subsequent attempt to shift the instance's `x` attribute bitwise would fail.

Again, the crux of the argument is the **mutability** inherent to regular members of a class.<sup>3</sup> Makes sense.

---

### Covariant subtyping in *normal* classes?

Here is where I run into problems. Why does the same logic **not apply**, when dealing with *normal* classes? Simple example (using dataclasses for convenience):

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Foo:
    x: float

@dataclass
class Bar(Foo):
    x: int

def f(obj: Foo) -> None:
    obj.x = 3.14

bar = Bar(1)
f(bar)
bar.x << 5  # This will fail at runtime
```

That code will pass `mypy --strict` without errors. This means **covariant** subtyping regarding the type of the `x` attribute is applied here.

I understand that it would make little sense to consider the call `f(bar)` an error because obviously `Bar` is a **nominal** subtype of `Foo`.<sup>4</sup> But why is the *definition* of `Bar` allowed *as is* in the first place?

Of course `int` is a subtype of `float`; no arguments here. But we are again dealing with a complex type, so variance considerations should apply like they do in the previous cases, shouldn't they?

Class members *are* mutable by default. Shouldn't regular classes therefore be considered **invaraint** with respect to their members, just like protocols are?

I would therefore expect the line `x: int` in the definition of `Bar` to trigger an error using the same logic as before. But it doesn't. Why?

---

### Pragmatism and consistency

I understand that there are and should be pragmatic considerations for decisions like these - whether something is covariant/contravariant/invariant. And there are even arguments made actively *against* the Liskov Substitution Principle in the context of method parameter types (to consider them covariant rather than contravaraint). Some of these arguments center around the claim that *"the world is covariant"*, such as in [this paper](https://se.inf.ethz.ch/%7Emeyer/ongoing/covariance/recast.pdf#G1040086) from 2003. Regardless of whether or not that makes sense, these considerations *should* at least be applied **consistently**.

And I struggle to see the consistency in the observations I made above.

---

**Footnotes:**

<sup>1</sup> Here the term "complex" simply means the type has itself *some* components with their own distinct type.

<sup>2</sup> The original code snippet from the Mypy docs simply set `x = 42` as a class attribute in the definition of `C`, which is enough to illustrate the point, but to be very precise (see comment by @chepner) I changed it to make `C.x` a "pure" instance attribute.

<sup>3</sup> The fact that the **mutability** of the member `x` is what causes the issue is further driven home in that section of the Mypy docs by suggesting `x` to be defined as a (non-settable) property to resolve the error.

<sup>4</sup> In contrast, with protocols the **structural** subtyping relation is obviously only checked at the call/assignment site, and an error can only arise, when an object is determined *not* to be a subtype of the variable type.

Comment: Regarding your second example, `C.x` is a new *class* attribute, unrelated to the instance attribute that `Protocol` mandates.

Comment: @chepner Yes and no. It's a class attribute and it _is_ related. As you know, after instantiation that class attribute will automatically become an instance attribute as well that can be mutated on the _instance_ without affecting the class attribute, which is why (I believe) the Mypy docs wrote the snippet that way. Regardless, the example behaves the same way, if you specifically make `x` a "pure" instance attribute. But if you like, I can amend the question to use an altered example instead of the one from the Mypy docs.

Comment: It does not become an instance attribute. If the attribute does not *exist*, then lookup will fall back to a class attribute of the same name. You can't modify a class attribute via an instance, because `c.x = ...` will always *create* an instance attribute instead of modifying the class attribute.

Comment: @chepner Fair enough. Thanks for the info. I did not realize the instance attribute is only created at that later point since even doing `c =  C()` `c.x += 1` `print(c.x, C.x)` will output `43 42`. But checking the instance's `__dict__` before and after that `__iadd__` shows that you are right. But again, I believe this is secondary to the matter at hand since the **implications for subtyping variance** are the same. Still, to be more precise I edited the example so that `x` is no longer a class attribute.

Comment: Yeah, I honestly don't have an answer for your broader question. It *feels* like instance attribute types should be taken into account (especially if you think of `c.x = ...` as syntactic sugar for `c.__setattr__('x', ...)`). I don't know if there is a formal argument for why this can't be the case, or if it's just a matter of it being too inconvenient to break typing for existing code.

Comment: History constraint in LSP requires modification only through methods, so in pure typing system *any* `instance.x = something` is forbidden (and attributes are more of property-like methods triplet, `get+set+delete`). It's way too much for typical python usage. Let's pretend we're good citizens and mean `instance.__setattr__('x', something: T) -> None` and `instance.__getattr__('x') -> T`. Here type `T` is used both as arg and as return type, so it must be invariant. I had this question before and ended up answering to myself "because things will be terribly unusable otherwise".

Comment: Not your question, but note latest mypy can check for covariant overrides as an opt-in check using `--enable-error-code mutable-override`. https://github.com/python/mypy/pull/16399