# mypy: how to specialize a child attribute type?

Tags: python, mypy

Here is what I'm trying to do: `Parent.x` can accept a `Literal` "a", "b", or "c". I would like a Child class that inherits from `Parent`, but whose `x` attributes can only be "a". Here is one of my attempts:

```
from typing import Literal

class Parent:
  x: Literal["a", "b", "c"]

  def __init__(self, x: Literal["a", "b", "c"]) -> None:
    self.x = x

class Child(Parent):
  x: Literal["a"]

child = Child("c") # this should return an error, but doesn't
```

As you can see, despite declaring the `x` attributes in Child as only accepting "a", I can still instantiate it with "c". I'm using mypy 1.3.0 with the `--strict` flag enabled.

Comment: What if you define `x` in `Child` class as `Final` ? : https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6824#issuecomment-1277078855 https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/final_attrs.html

Comment: `Final` would prevent assignment to the instance attribute at all. Final values must be initialized immediately.

Comment: The annotation in `Child` only affects methods of `Child` that try to set the attribute. You didn't define `Child.__init__`, so `Parent.__init__` is called and uses the type hint supplied by `Parent`. I'm not sure if there is a way to "override" a type annotation like this.

Comment: (More precisely, you could use `Final` in *`Parent`*, but then you cannot redefine it `Child`.)

Comment: so my only option to allow for dynamically setting the x value and have strong type checking is to define Child.__init__, even if it will be for all intent and purpose the same as the one in Parent? That's not great :/

Comment: I'm not sure it's even legitimate to restrict the type of an attribute like this in a subclass, at least if it's writeable, due to the Liskov Substitution Principle. (Imagine `L: list[Parent] = [...]; L[0].x = "c"`. Statically, that should be legitimate, but it's not if `L[0]` is actually an instance of `Child`.)

Comment: Interesting, and it does make sense when you explain it that way. But then I feel mypy should return an error when I overrides the parent symbol, even if I overrides it with a subclass of the parent attribute. Wouldn't that make more sense? Or am I missing something?

Comment: This could be a bug in `mypy`. Say I define `def foo(self) -> Literal["a"]: return self.x` in `Child`. That type checks, even though there's no code that actually ensures the `self.x` is a `Literal["a"]` value.

Comment: Thank you for your great help! I opened an issue with mypy: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/15455

Comment: @chepner see comments here regarding LSP and attributes covariant overriding: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76005083/why-is-covariant-subtyping-of-mutable-members-allowed

Comment: @MyUsername112358 the class you describe just should be generic. Currently your `__init__` and `x` values are unrelated. Make them related to get a working solution: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=879c64610f33d80db5cd8cdfc50c37ea

Comment: @SUTerliakov-supportsstrike Thanks. I even upvoted your comment at that time. :facepalm: